# Thread started by itself

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = Thread(target=main_programm(1, int(maximum/4)))
a.daemon = True
b = Thread(target=main_programm(int(maximum/4), int(maximum/3)))
b.daemon = True
c = Thread(target=main_programm(int(maximum/3), int(maximum/2)))
c.daemon = True
d = Thread(target=main_programm(int(maximum/2), maximum))
d.daemon = True


print("Done!")
#------------end of programm------------#
```

all the threads are running without even starting them ;(
dont know why this is happaning
hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a function, you run it. Pass the arguments as using the `args` keyword like so.

```
a = Thread(target=main_programm, args=(1, int(maximum/4)))
a.daemon = True
b = Thread(target=main_programm, args=(int(maximum/4), int(maximum/3)))
b.daemon = True
c = Thread(target=main_programm, args=(int(maximum/3), int(maximum/2)))
c.daemon = True
d = Thread(target=main_programm, args=(int(maximum/2), maximum))
d.daemon = True

a.start()
b.start()
c.start()
d.start()

print("Done!")
#------------end of programm------------#
```